# Prove a Predicate is Primitive Recursive

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, logic, recurrence-relation, primitive-recursion

Suppose $x$ is Godel's number of some formula. Predicate $\operatorname{P}(\operatorname{f}(x))$ is true only when the number of functions is equal to the number of predicates in that formula.

Prove that $\operatorname{P}(\operatorname{f}(x))$ is primitive recursive.

My Godel Numbering system is

$$G(\forall)=1$$
$$G(()=3$$
$$G(()=5$$
$$G(\neg)=7$$
$$G(\implies)=11$$
$$G(a_i)=7+8i\ where \ a_i\  is\  constant $$
$$G(x_i)=5+8i\ where \ x_i\  is\  variable $$
$$G(f_i^j)=9+8*2^i*3^j\ where \ f_i^j\  is\  function $$
$$G(P_i^j)=11+8*2^i*3^j\ where \ P_i^j\  is\  predicate $$

For sequence of symbols
$$G(u_0u_1...u_n)=2^{G(u_0)}*3^{G(u_1)}...P_r^{G(u_n)}\ where\  2,3,...P_r\  \ are\  prime\  numbers$$

I tried to group predicates and functions and make a claim that if we find the biggest divisor of x that has a form $s=y^9*x^2*y^{48w}$, where
$y=q_1*q_2...*q_{2p},\ $  $x=q_2*q_4...*q_{2p},\ $ and if we divide $x$ by $s$ there will be no divisors of form $f^9*f^{48m}\ $ or $f^{11}*f^{48m}\ $. But I am not sure about this claim and it seems very hard to prove the primitive recursivity of such function.

Comment: As described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function), a primitive recursive function is equivalent to a program without any while loops, just for loops. The idea behind the for loop constraint is that it provides an upper bound on the amount of computation done by the program. So for your particular problem at hand, all you have to do is write a program that uses a for loop to first count the predicates, and then another for a loop to count the functions....(ran out of room...)

Comment: ....And these loops are bounded above by the total number of characters in your formulas, because not every character in your formula can be a function or predicate. So there's no need to do any Gödel numbering.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about the question. I have the formal solution using notations from Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/mendelson.pdf.